# How do I install all win32screenshot Ruby gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have been trying to install the `win32screenshot` gem but am getting the following DependencyError:

```
C:\Ruby200\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems>gem install mini_magick-4.6.1.gem win32screenshot-2.1.0.gem

Successfully installed mini_magick-4.6.1
Parsing documentation for mini_magick-4.6.1
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
Unable to resolve dependencies: win32screenshot requires mini_magick (~> 4.3.0)"
```

Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Vasile

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: @Tsao I'm running Windows 7